# Removal of main OK, Glass menu items

Tags: google-gdk

I would like to reduce the Ok, Glass main menu items - e.g. remove various apps including camera. 
Am after a simpler, less cluttered Ok, Glass interface.

Before I do the adb uninstall, will I be able to recover those apps and put them back?
Thanks

Comment: Why go through this process?! What value add are you bringing?

Comment: Its due to using an app in a very secure area where recording equipment is not permitted. Hence must show clearly that its been removed.

Answer (score 0):

Got it - found the apps stored on the device via DDMS, copied them from the device. Uninstalled many default apps and successfully put them back again. You just have to track down the .apks in the respective folder (priv).